# How to proof that a function is well defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Let (G, °) be a cyclic group with |G|= *n* (*n* of N), that is generated by *a* of G.
Zn --> G, [k]-> *a*^k ; (Zn,+) and (G;°).

How do I proof that the function is well-defined?

I already proofed that is a Homomorphism, but I don't know how to proof that it is well-defined. Do I have to proof that it is injective ?

Comment: The (possible) problem with the definition is that you have to choose a representative for the equivalence class $[k]$.  You must show that the map doesn't change if you change that representative.

Comment: In other words, prove that $[k]=[l]\implies f([k])=f([l])$. Note that k may not be equal to l.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to proof it now. Big thanks!